# How to combine 2 strings from different functions in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine two user input strings from different functions and then have it print as one statement. I know to combine two regular strings (ones not in a function) I would use the '+' function, but I can't figure out how to do it with user input being from two different functions. Can anyone help? here is my code:

```
def get_first_name(first_name):
    first_name = str(input('what is your first name?'))
    len_firstName = 0
    while len_firstName <= 0:
            print('that is not valid, please try again.')
            first_name = str(input('what is your first name?'))
            len_firstName = len(first_name)
            print(len(first_name))
    return first_name

get_first_name(input)


def get_last_name(last_name):
    last_name = str(input('what is your last name?'))
    count_of_last_name = len(last_name)
    if count_of_last_name < 1: 
        print('There is no last name.')
    else:
        print(last_name)
    return last_name

get_last_name(input)

# This is what I am trying to do to combine the two but it doesn't work and I'm stuck:

full_name = get_first_name + get_last_name
print(full_name)
```

Comment: The functions *return* the strings; you need to save the return values when you call the functions, not use the function name itself as if it were the string returned.

Comment: There appears to be no reason for either function to accept an argument. It's ignored and replace with user input immediately. Passing the `input` function to each of them is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, using the `+` operator is the way to go. You meant to write: `full_name = get_first_name(input) + get_last_name(input)`. However, please take into account the comment above about the redundant `input` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The main misunderstanding here seems mostly based around how functions should be structured. To get the behavior you want, define two distinct functions: `get_first_name` and `get_last_name`. These functions should ***accept no parameters***, and instead ***return*** a string which you read from input (*parameters would be necessary if you are passing data IN to the function, but your goal here is to get a name value OUT*).

You can then define a `get_full_name` function where you call each, and combine their results. Call this function, remembering that function calls must *end with parentheses*. Your result may look something like this! Notice how the print statement is not inside a function definition, so it is executed when you run your program.

```py
# define functions
def get_first_name():
  first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
  return first_name

def get_last_name():
  last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
  return last_name

def get_full_name():
  full_name = get_first_name() + " " + get_last_name()
  return full_name

# call your full_name function
print("Hello, " + get_full_name())
```

Let me know if any of that is unclear!

Comment: Please can you explain just why the functions should accept no parameters. This might not be obvious to a new contributor.

Comment: The first name can't be empty like in the OP code

Comment: Hi Ethan! What you said makes sense, the only issue is that I need all the code that's in my first and last name functions for other parts of my assignment. Is there a different way I can still get my program to print the user's first and last name without deleting my existing code?

Answer (score 1):

I would say Ethan answerd your question about why the functions dont work perfectly.
What I'd like to add is a reworked version of your first function

```
def get_first_name():
    first_name = ''
    while len(first_name) == 0:
        first_name = input('what is your first name?\n')
        if len(first_name) == 0:
            print('that is not valid, please try again.')
    return first_name


print(get_first_name())
```

In your version you'd always get a 'not valid' message even if the input is valid.

As to why your functions don't need any attributes, maybe my silly painting might help :)

or this code:

```
def output(first_name):
    print('my first name is ' + first_name)

my_name = 'ovski'

output(my_name)
```

The (first_name) in def output is an attribute that is used inside the function.

In other words:

- 'ovski' is stored inside the variable my_name
- my_name is given as attribute into the function output
- output uses the values inside the attribute and - combines it with the string 'my first name is '

[function with attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApmXb.png)

Comment: Have you tried your function?

Comment: I guess we are talking about the missing return statement? I edited the first function. Guess you are talking bout this one.

Comment: Exactly, That what I meant. Thanks for noticing and editing that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I noticed that before but couldn't quite figure out why it was doing that... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. I change your string line and it worked.

```
def get_first_name(first_name):
    first_name = str(input('what is your first name?'))
    len_firstName = 0
    while len_firstName > 0:
            print('that is not valid, please try again.')
            first_name = str(input('what is your first name?'))
            len_firstName = len(first_name)
            print(len(first_name))
    return first_name

def get_last_name(last_name):
    last_name = str(input('what is your last name?'))
    count_of_last_name = len(last_name)
    if count_of_last_name < 1: 
        print('There is no last name.')
    else:
        print(last_name)
    return last_name

# This is what I am trying to do to combine the two but it doesn't work and I'm stuck:

full_name = get_first_name(input) + " " + get_last_name(input)   

#Basically, you never stored/assigned the return values of your functions to someting

print(full_name)
```

Comment: This does not checking or validating user input  when the input is empty or its length is equals 0 as the original OP's code does.

Comment: Yes, I know but that wasn't the question above. He just wanted to combine the inputs. The validation and checking should be part of the functions.

Comment: I agree, this code solved OP question, but shouldn't  cause another problem. Just leave it as it is, if it does not provide the same or better behaviour like original. Pointing only OP question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prompt/validate user input when there is no input or empty, you can check if `first_name` and `last_name` is true or false with `while not` statement.

To avoid redundant input, you can use walrus operator `:=` in `while` and `if` statement.

Your function does not need parameter, except if there are inputs or any variables outside the function that need to be passed in.

To combine return value of the `get_first_name()` and `get_last_name()` function into variable `full_name`, you can use `f-string`.

```
def get_first_name():
    while not (first_name := (input('what is your first name? '))):
        print('that is not valid, please try again.')
    return first_name


def get_last_name():
    if not (last_name := (input('what is your last name? '))):
        print('There is no last name.')
    return last_name


full_name = f'{get_first_name()} {get_last_name()}'
print(full_name)

# what is your first name? 
# that is not valid, please try again.
# what is your first name? John
# what is your last name? 
# There is no last name.
# John
```